# How to approach item count checker

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I'm trying to create a trigger to disable the combobox drop down button if there are no items. This is the XAML code I've tried so far, however I am unsure of how to detect whether there are no items contained in the ComboBox, and how to disable the button which drops down the list specifically.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Items.Count" Value="0">

                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource=
   {RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=ItemsSource.Count}"/>
```

Assuming whatever you have bound to your ItemsSource property has a count method (it worked for ObservableCollection).  It's actually kind of interesting that count being 0 resolves to false in xaml, however this wouldn't be the case in C#.

You can add it to a style if you need to add it to a control programatically

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="ComboStyle">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding RelativeSource=
       {RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=ItemsSource.Count}"/>
</Style>
```

```
ComboBox cbo = new ComboBox();
cbo.ItemsSource = MyData;
cbo.Style = Resources["ComboStyle"] as Style;
```

Comment: The ComboBox is created at run-time though. Would it be possible to adapt that as a trigger which is triggered by the items count being 0?

Comment: @DotNET Tested changing the number of items at run-time and my code still worked for me, again this is assuming the `ItemsSource` is an `ObservableCollection`, since this automatically will fire the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and update the UI (If it weren't you would probably need to fire it manually)

Comment: Yes, it is an ObservableCollection, however where am I supposed to place your code if the ComboBox itself is generated at run-time?

Comment: @DotNET You could create a style that did the same thing, added a bit to my code.

Comment: The combobox still isnt disabling itself:/

Comment: @DotNET odd, it worked for me, maybe post some more code of how you are actually generating the combo box?